# Linked List contains lines from a text file. Create find(int index) method which prints the content at the index positions passed as an argument

Tags: java, linked-list

Please find the below code snippet for printing the content at index position passed as an argument. The list prepared contains the line read from a text file. It looks like
[ The abc......
  ....
]

Please correct it if anything wrong.

```
public class ContactList {
    private ContactNode head;
    private ContactNode last;
    public ContactNode current;
    public ContactList() {}
    public void addNode(ContactNode input) {
        if(this.head == null) {
            this.head = input;
            this.last = input;
        } else
            last.setNext(input);
       input.setPrev(last);
       this.last = input;
   }
    public void traverse() { 
        System.out.println();
        current = this.head; 
        while (current != null) {
          System.out.print( current.getName() + " ");
          System.out.println("");
          current = current.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public void getFirst() {
        current = this.head; 
        while (current != null) {  
            System.out.print("The first contact of the list is: "
                        + current.getName());
            break;
        }
    } 
    public void getLast(){      
        current = this.last; 
        while (current != null) {  
            System.out.print("The Last contact of the list is: " 
                        + current.getName());
            break;
        }
    }
    public ContactNode find(int index) {
        ContactNode current = head;
        while(current!=null) {
            if(current.getIndex() == (index))
                System.out.println(current.getName());
            else 
                current = current.getNext();
            System.out.println(current);
        }
            return null;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

```
public class ContactNode{

private String name;
public int index;
private ContactNode prev;
public ContactNode next;

ContactNode(String a)
{ name = a;
index = 0;
next = null;
prev = null;}

ContactNode(){}

public ContactNode getNext()
{return next;}
public ContactNode getPrev()
{return prev;}
public String getName()
{return name;}
public int getIndex(){
return index;}

public  void setNext(ContactNode newnext)
{next = newnext;}
public  void setPrev(ContactNode newprevious)
{prev = newprevious;}
public void setName(String a)
{name=a;}
public void setIndex(int b)
{index=b;}

}
```

Main method class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class ContactMain{
public static void main(String[]args){
try{
FileReader filepath = new FileReader("data1.txt");
Scanner k = new Scanner(filepath);
ContactList myList = new ContactList();
while (k.hasNextLine()){
String i = k.nextLine(); 
myList.addNode(new ContactNode(i));}


myList.traverse();
myList.getFirst();
myList.getLast();
myList.find(3);

}catch (FileNotFoundException e){
System.out.println("File Not Found. ");}}}
```

Comment: I am also using a scanner class in the main method class

Comment: This find method doesn't return anything. I am trying to make it so the user inputs the index and the method gets the index from the list and prints the value or contact in that spot in the list. The program also contains two other programs: a main method class and node class. I create the list in the main method and have getIndex() and setIndex() methods created in the Node class titled ContactNode.java and the mainmethodclass called: ContactMain.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing in your find method, actually return the node that you find.
Also it's unclear if your `ContactNode` class actually has a `getIndex()` method, so I'm going to assume it doesn't. In order to make up for this, we keep track of a count (with `head = 0`).

```
public ContactNode find(int index) {
        ContactNode current = head;
        while(current!=null) {
            if(index == 0)
                return current;

            //we're not there yet. Move to next node, decrement index
            current = current.getNext();
            index--;
        }
        return null;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the pointers. I like your suggestion. It is better than my find method because it is less messy. However, my program does contain a getIndex() and setIndex() method in the class ContactNode. The same problem occurs as it doesn't print anything at all. Maybe I should upload all the programs too?

Comment: Yeah, go ahead and put them all up in your original post.

Comment: Ok @Mshnik 

I have successfully uploaded the extra programs to help you further evaluate.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have figured out my problem. It works fine with a print statement(is that bad habit? Bad Coding?). Thank you again.

Comment: It's not horribly bad, but do ask yourself if it's working or it only *looks* like its working from the printing output. As in try to print other stuff about the list that should be true after some operations. And no problem! Upvotes/acceptance appreciated.